# text file not updated after write c# Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-8, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm trying to write string data into a text file in a Windows Phone 8 app but the text file just would not be updated.

I'm writing with the codes below

```
public void update_file(Contact_List[] list) //Write to file
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"contact_list.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < list.Length; x++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(list[x].first_name);
                    sw.WriteLine(list[x].last_name);
                    sw.WriteLine(list[x].number);
                    sw.WriteLine(list[x].email);
                    sw.WriteLine(list[x].company);
                    sw.WriteLine(list[x].favorite);
                    sw.WriteLine(list[x].group);
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

Where Contact_List is my custom struct which contains the following string:

1. public string first_name;
2. public string last_name;
3. public string email;
4. public string number;
5. public string company;
6. public string favorite;
7. public string group;

The program itself could be run without any error which including the reading and even during the program the written contents could be display in the list box but the written contents would never be updated in the actual file.

The reading part is the following

```
public class All_Contact : common_func //Counting number of lines in the file
{
    public int count_lines()
    {
        int counter = 0;

        var str = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"contact_list.txt", UriKind.Relative));
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str.Stream);
        while (sr.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        sr.Close();
        sr.Dispose();
        str.Stream.Close();
        str.Stream.Dispose();
        return counter;
    }

public string[][] read_content (int ln) //Read and pick up the actual contents
    {
        string[][] temp = null;
        int lines = ln;
        temp = new string[lines / 7][];
        var str = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"contact_list.txt", UriKind.Relative));
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str.Stream);
        for (int x = 0; x < (lines / 7); x++)
        {
            temp[x] = new string[7];
            for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
            {
                temp[x][y] = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
        sr.Dispose();
        str.Stream.Close();
        str.Stream.Dispose();
        return temp;
    }
```

I'm very new to programming with Windows Phone 8 application so I don't have any idea how are the things working in background therefore any detailed explanation will be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Write a very simple program (using StreamWriter) that creates a simple file in the same directory as this program is using, and make sure it runs.

Comment: Yes I did make a simple testing program using streamwriter but it just acted the same what I had in my main program.

Comment: OK, now post that simple program here instead.  It will be easier for others to comment on.

Comment: problem solved! seems like windows phone 8 doesn't support write file with StreamWriter I should have use Isolated Storage!

Comment: Check this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5259d6f5-f992-4977-9073-a394071138f4/error-access-to-the-path-cdataprogramsinstallsoundflac-is-denied?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Great.  Please post your "problem solved" comment as an answer and accept your own answer, so that the question can be finalized.

Comment: Right I'm using IsolatedStorageSettings for my file io. For example : `settings_obj.Add("username", textBox1.Text);` to write, and `textBox2.Text = settings_obj["username"];` to read

Comment: Thanks a lot Sabuncu, and I'm sorry about making so many inconvenience.